# htaccess rewrite working but browser/bot still showing 404

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to show content based on a non-existing actual URL. There's only one PHP file and that's index.php where I'm checking the URL parts and based on the name of the parts, I'm pulling the according data off a database. To not get actual 404 errors I use the rewrite module. It works like I hoped but still shows "kind-of" 404 errors which results in Google not being able to index the pages. Firebug and others show a 404 but display the content.

URL:

```
www.example.com/page
```

PHP:

```
$page = str_replace('/index.php?', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php
```

Is there a solution where the browser/bot doesn't show a 404 error?

Comment: What does  "kind-of" 404 errors mean?

Comment: Sorry. I meant that the actual content is showing on the website and not a 404-error page hovever, firebug and bots show a 404 error which results in Google not being able to index the page.

Comment: Add a firbug screenshot showing all the headers getting passed to and fro when accessing the page.